# What does the voltage of an electrode mean at higher frequency AC currents?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

Consider a parallel plate capacitor. If a DC potential difference of $2V_{0}$ is provided across the capacitor then we can define an electrostatic scalar potential by solving Poisson's equation using the plates as boundary conditions. The electrostatic force is related to this scalar potential by
$$
\textbf{E}(\textbf{r},t)=-\nabla V(\textbf{r},t). 
$$

In electrodynamics, it is necessary to describe the electric field using both a scalar potential, $\phi(\textbf{r},t)$ and a vector potential, $\textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)$,
$$\textbf{E}(\textbf{r},t)=-\nabla \phi(\textbf{r},t)-\frac{\partial\textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)}{\partial t}.$$

Consider the same parallel capacitor with an AC potential is supplied across the plates at high enough frequency for the electrostatic approximation to become invalid. In what way are $\phi(\textbf{r},t)$ and $\textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)$ dependent on voltage of the electrodes? And how does this change under a gauge transformation to

$$(\phi',\textbf{A}')=\left(\phi+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t},\textbf{A}-\nabla f\right).$$

Comment: If the electrostatic potential isn't valid in the dielectric, what makes you think it's valid on the electrodes?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: You asked about the "voltage on the electrodes". This is usually another way of saying the potential difference between the electrodes. But this is a situation where the electrostatic potential is not well defined. So you should say more explicitly what you mean by the "voltage on the electrodes".

Comment: What @thephoton is saying is that by writing $\textbf{E}(\textbf{r},t)=-\nabla V(\textbf{r},t)$ you explicitly indicated that $E$ is *time varying*. A regular voltmeter can measure *some* ac voltage but it is not unique, because $\text{curl} \mathbf E \ne 0$ you must specify what this ac voltage means to you. (You have a sign error in your last equation).

Comment: I suppose the question then becomes what does it mean to apply an AC power supply accross the electrodes at these frequencies

Answer (score 0):

If the electrostatic approximation doesn't apply, you have an antenna. An antenna is a much more complicated thing than a capacitor. To model it, you need a detailed geometric description, including a description of the "feed" which supplies energy to to the system to maintain your oscillating fields. Once you have that, you have some tricky calculations to do.